# Issues in site after adding SSL certificate

Tags: php, jquery, openssl

My whole site is based on jquery ajax and after adding SSL certificate to site, ajax is not working request is posted but there is no response except 200 ok.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is a bit unspecific,

1. Have you changed the protocol of your request URLs to **https** instead of **http** ?
2. Is your SSL certificate valid and working ? Is your webserver correctly configurated? Are usual https through your browser successful? Maybe you have to manually accept the certificate, if it's self-generated.

Comment: 1. YES, 2. YES.   >--> In all pages ajax is working fine in http but while i use https in some pages ajax is working while in some pages ajax request is send but stopped without giving any response in mozilla firbug it looks in red POST https://completepath/(it is working fine when hit directly in new window) 200 OK 610ms  and in right jquery.min.js(line 5)

Comment: @Raju Jain Is it possible for you to provide us a testing environment of your application? It's very hard to tell without more certain information.